# Is there a way to ignore existing tables when using Propel?

Tags: php, propel

I am using Propel for PHP and I want to create a diff task to create new tables.

The issue is this is inside an existing database with tables already existing.  I don't want these tables to be managed by Propel.  When doing the diff task, it looks at these tables.  Anyway to ignore these tables during the diff process?

Answer (score 1):

No, migration tasks are quite dumb at the moment. That's why you always need to review generated diff classes.